# ng-model and value combination not working for input text box

Tags: javascript, angularjs, input, angular-ngmodel

I'm having two input text box.
I need to combine the values entered in two text boxes and display it in the third.
I'm able to display it if I use only the `value` in the third text box.

Box 1:

```
 <input type="text" ng-model="entity.name">
```

Box 2:

```
 <input type="text" ng-model="entity.code">
```

Box 3:Box1+Box 2

```
  <input type="text" value="{{entity.name+ ' + ' + entity.code}}">
```

However if I use a model name in the third box, the logic doesn't seem to be working:

```
 <input type="text" value="{{entity.name+ ' + ' + entity.code}}" 
        ng-model="entity.fullCode">
```

Can anyone suggest a fix ??

Comment: have u tried `ng-value`?

Comment: What does the "the logic doesn't seem to be working" mean? What is the "logic"?

Comment: @New Dev ,Binding of the values from two text boxes

Comment: @Foo.I tried.Its not working

Comment: In other words, you expect `entity.fullCode` to equal the concatenation of the first two?

Comment: In your controller, there should be a `$scope.entity.fullCode = $scope.entity.name + $scope.entity.code`

Comment: Should I add it inside any function?? @Foo bcoz it dosen't get triggered as you enter values in the text box

Comment: You need to put that in your angular controller

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a good question as it illustrates how incorrect "thinking in Angular" can lead to issues.

With Angular you start with model first. Then the View is bound to the model and reflects it - not the other way around. What I mean by that is that `ng-value` would not set the model, although it would alter the view. You (or rather, the controller) is responsible for setting the model.

So, if you need `entity.fullCode` to equal the concatenation of `entity.name` and `entity.code`, then you should set it in the controller.

For example, if you wanted to set it any time `entity.name` or `entity.code` change, then you could do so with `$watch`:

```
$scope.$watch("entity.name + entity.code", function(newVal){
   $scope.entity.fullCode = $scope.entity.name + "+" + $scope.entity.code;
})
```

Note, though, that since you are binding `entity.fullCode` to another input, changing that input would change `entity.fullCode` and would not make it equal to the `+` of the first two.

Comment: Creating a $watch for this is a bit overkill, no? Also, I believe he's trying to end up with something like this as an example: "something + something" -- where the string literally includes the + character.

Comment: @MEANDeveloper, fixed the "+"... It's hard to say that this is an overkill as it is not clear what the ultimate goal is. Should it only be changed by the two input boxes? Then `ng-change` on each would be better. Btw, deep watch (as in another answer) is definitely less efficient

Comment: You're right. It's easy to fall into this kind of thinking as I did.

Answer (score 2):

```
<div ng-app>
  <div>
    <label>Name:</label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="entity.name">
    <label>Code:</label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="entity.code">
    <label>Full Code:</label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="entity.fullCode" value="{{entity.fullCode=entity.name + ' + ' + entity.code}}">
  </div>
</div>
```

You must assign something to your ng-model attribute, so that it can bind. 
your code seems to be work. but just display purpose we do this. 
cheers

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `$watch with true`

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.entity={name:'',code:'',fullCode:''};
    $scope.$watch('entity',function(n,o){
        $scope.entity.fullCode = $scope.entity.name + $scope.entity.code;
    },true);

}
```

Fiddle:- http://jsfiddle.net/405qc0xg/

Comment: Glad to help you out.

Comment: @MANOJ, careful with deep-watch (with `true`). If you have a large or nested object, this would be extremely inefficient. It's often cheaper to shallow-watch an expression: `$watch("entity.name + entity.code", ...)`

Answer (score 1):

```
$scope.entity = [];    
$scope.entity.name = "";    
$scope.entity.code = "";    

$scope.$watch("entity.name + entity.code", function(newVal){

    if($scope.entity.name != "" && $scope.entity.code != ""){
        $scope.entity.fullCode = $scope.entity.name + "+" + $scope.entity.code;
    }
    else {
        $scope.entity.fullCode = "";
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

**you need to make use of $watch.** 
It keeps watch on mentioned obeject as soon as value of object change the function of $watch will be called and it will refresh $scope
for your code your need to write this:

```js
$scope.$watch('entity.name',function(){
        $scope.entity.fullCode=$scope.entity.name+' + '+$scope.entity.code;
    });
    $scope.$watch('entity.code',function(){
        $scope.entity.fullCode=$scope.entity.name+' + '+$scope.entity.code;
    });
```

Comment: downvote for dup code. You can use `$watchGroup` and pass an array with both name & code

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using controllerAs syntax and would suggest you do something like this in your controller:

```
entity.fullCode = entity.name + ' - ' + entity.code;
```

Then you can drop the value attribute and simply bind to the element via data-ng-model/ng-model.

Comment: .Am not using ControllerAs syntax.

Comment: Then simply use $scope.entity.whatever instead :) See if that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps you, please have a look into the plunker

http://plnkr.co/edit/oMUABphr6JcNEhCnCDKq?p=preview

```
$scope.obj = {first : '',second : ''};

$scope.$watch('obj', function(newval, oldval){
  $scope.obj.third = $scope.obj.first + $scope.obj.second;  
},true)
```

The above code says, when ever the object 'obj' changes, then the code inside the $watch will execute.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should actually work. See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m4n7gj8t/) for a working demo.

```
<div ng-app>
  <div>
    <label>Name:</label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="entity.name">
    <label>Code:</label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="entity.code">
    <label>Full Code:</label>
    <input type="text" value="{{entity.name + ' + ' + entity.code}}">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It indeed works.But how can I set the value to the model.That's the problem?

Comment: Ah I see what you mean, then you should go with the accepted answer by @new-dev. It watches `entity.name` and `entity.code` for changes and explicitly creates/updates a third model value.