# ng-model and value not working for input from google autocomplete forms

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, input

I am trying to take values selected from google autocomplete for forms and assign them to inputs. This works perfectly until I give them ng-model, at which point the input becomes blank. I've read [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28339586/ng-model-and-value-combination-not-working-for-input-text-box?rq=1) that I need to assign the value in the controller instead of the html as I am currently doing.

Here is the full code: http://plnkr.co/edit/qy9nNj4QM3J1S95ruBGh?p=preview

Here is the specific part I am trying to use to do this:

```
<input ng-model="focus" ng-change="chosenPlace=focus" details="chosenPlaceDetails" placeholder="" googleplace />

<input class="input-field" type="text" id="city-input" ng-model="formData.city" />

$scope.$watch("focus", function(newVal){
   $scope.formData.city = $scope.chosenPlaceDetails.address_components[2].long_name;
})
```

But I still get no result. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Install Places autocomplete `min.js` file first and include it in your directive. Like shown in the snippet.

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&sensor=false"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="../ngPlacesAutocomplete.min.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

It has to be after Google api but before app.js.

Refer to this [GitHub example](https://github.com/Charminbear/ngPlacesAutocomplete) for detailed explanation of the implementation.